# Autohotkey - Using DOM, trigger javascript function

Tags: javascript, function, dom, triggers, autohotkey

There are some buttons(actually, links) on a web, and I can click on it menually.

but,

> wb:=ComObjCreate("InternetExplorer.Application")
>
> wb.document.getElementById("Status").click()

this script don't work. @critsz said because there is no definition about click.

so, I'm trying to trigger the function after defining "click"

the following is a part of the source.

```
 <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked" id="TabMenu">
    <li class="active" id="basic"><a href="javascript:viewPage('basic','10010');"><i class="fa fa-inbox"></i> Basic</a>
        <!-- <span class="label label-primary pull-right">12</span> -->
    </li>
    <li id="Status"><a href="javascript:viewPage('Status','10010');"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i> Status</a></li>
 </ul> 
    

function viewPage(Name,Number){

$("#TabMenu li").removeClass("active");
$("#"+Name).addClass("active");

$("#ViewPage").load(
    Name+".asp",
    {
        Number : Number 
    },
    function( response, status, xhr ) {
        if ( status == "error" ) {
            var msg = "an error: ";
            $( "#error" ).html( msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText );
        }
});
}
```

And I tried this.

> wb.document.getElementById("Status").addEventListener("click",viewPage(Status,10000))

but an error occurs : Call to nonexistent function.
Specifically: viewPage(Status,10000)

Does this mean that I need to define the function on my autohotkey script? or Is there any other way to do that?

if i should do, how can I do that?

Comment: `viewPage(Status,10000)`, you miss the quotes around the `Status` word

Comment: @ltamajs you mean viewPage("Status","1000")? this show same error massage too. and viewPage('Status','10000') occur error: the leftmost character is illegal

Answer (score 0):

Try `wb.navigate("javascript:viewPage('Status','10010');")`